# Code not executed after PUT route using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I listen to the chat event of the [tmijs library](https://docs.tmijs.org/), upon the `!overlay` chat I want to execute some code. What I want to achieve upon getting that message is:

- Fetch the user
- Check if the user has enough currency
- Deduct currency from the user
- Trigger a socket event to my react app

Everything seems to work up until the last bullet point. In my terminal it's shown that my user gets currency (called 'kluiten' in my code) deducted, but all the code that comes after it doesn't get executed.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

class TwitchAPI {
  constructor({io}) {
    this.io = io;
    this.client = new tmi.client(options);

    this.client.connect();

    this.handleOverlayRequest = this.handleOverlayRequest.bind(this);
    this.handleChatMessage = this.handleChatMessage.bind(this);

    this.client.on('chat', this.handleChatMessage);
  }

  handleChatMessage (channel, userstate, message) {
   if(message === '!overlay') this.handleOverlayRequest(channel, userstate);
  }

  async handleOverlayRequest (channel, userstate) {
    const requiredKluiten = 5;
    const rawFoundUser = await fetch(`http://localhost:${PORT}/api/users/${userstate.username}`);
    const foundUser = await rawFoundUser.json();

    if(foundUser.instakluiten >= requiredKluiten) {
      this.client.action(channel, `${userstate[`display-name`]}, you've got enough instakluiten for this.`);

      const method = `PUT`;
      const payload = { 'requiredKluiten': requiredKluiten };
      const body = JSON.stringify(payload);
      const headers = { 'Content-Type': `application/json; charset=utf-8` };

      const result = await fetch(`http://localhost:${PORT}/api/users/${userstate.username}/decrementKluiten`, { method, body, headers });
      console.log(result);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = TwitchAPI;
```

I then have an Express router:

```
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');

const router = express.Router();

router.route('/users/:username/decrementKluiten').put(userController.decrementKluiten);
router.route('/users/:username').get(userController.getUser);
router.route('/overview').get(userController.getOverview);

module.exports = router;
```

which makes sure the currency gets deducted. What I'm stuck on now is that, after all this has happened, I can't execute any code anymore after the fetch. I found though that I could execute code by resolving the promise in my route, but that feels really dirty and messes up my split up files:

```
router.route('/users/:username/decrementKluiten').put((req, res) => {
 userController.decrementKluiten(req, res).then(x => {
  console.log(x);
 });
});
```

Is there a way to wait for my PUT to happen and still execute code after it did?

**EDIT**

userController.js

```
const {findChattersPerRole, getUserByUsername, decrementKluiten} = require('../actions');
const find = require(`lodash/find`);
const fetch = require(`isomorphic-fetch`);
const parseJSON = response => response.json();

module.exports = {
  getUser: (req, res) => {
    const username = req.params.username;
    findChattersPerRole()
      .then(chattersPerRole => {
        const wantedUser = find(chattersPerRole, { username });
        getUserByUsername(wantedUser.username)
          .then(foundUser => {
            if (foundUser) {
              res.send(foundUser);
            } else {
              res.send(`No user has been found`);
            }
          });
      });
  },
  getOverview: (req, res) => {
    fetch(`https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/instak/chatters`)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(r => {
      return res.json(r);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  },
  decrementKluiten: (req, res) => {
    decrementKluiten(req.params.username, req.body.requiredKluiten);
  }
}
```

actions.js

(*Because this contains a lot of code I try to only include the relevant parts for this post, the database calls are done using Sequelize.js*)

```
const decrementKluiten = (username, requiredKluiten) => {
  return global.db.Viewer.findOne({
    where: { username }
  }).then(user => {
    return user.decrement({ instakluiten: requiredKluiten });
  });
};

module.exports = {
  decrementKluiten
};
```

Comment: Would be great if you could include the relevant code from the `userController` module.

Comment: @Svenskunganka I added the most relevant parts.

Comment: In the `userController.js`-file, the exported `decrementKluiten` method, if you replace its code with `decrementKluiten(req.params.username, req.body.requiredKluiten).then(() => res.sendStatus(200)).catch(() => res.sendStatus(500))`, does it work then? I wonder if we could perhaps open a chat for this, I expect we might have to do some debugging and I have some unrelated pointers for you.

Comment: Damn that works man. Smart move to split up the sendStatus. I knew I had to intervene before the status was sent, but didn't think of doing it like that although that's fairly easy. You should add it as an answer so I can approve it because this just helped me out. I'm still open for some feedback, the unrelated pointers though!

Comment: Lovely, glad it worked out! I'll compose an answer for you with some pointers and post it in a few minutes! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that you don't respond to the HTTP request in your `/users/:username/decrementKluiten` route. To solve this, change the exported `decrementKluiten` method in `userController.js`-file to this:

```
decrementKluiten: (req, res) => {
  decrementKluiten(req.params.username, req.body.requiredKluiten)
    .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
    .catch(() => res.sendStatus(500));
}
```

---

Some unrelated pointers to make your code a bit more readable, since you already use `async` functions in some parts of your code, but in other parts you interface directly with Promises.

The exported part of `userController.js` could utilize `async` functions:

```
module.exports = {
  getUser: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const username = req.params.username;
      let chattersPerRole = await findChattersPerRole();
      let wantedUser = find(chattersPerRole, { username });
      let foundUser = await getUserByUsername(watnerUser.username);
      if (foundUser) {
        res.status(200).send(foundUser);
      } else {
        res.status(404).send('No user has been found');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  },
  getOverview: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      let r = (await fetch('https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/instak/chatters')).json();
      res.json(r);
    } catch (e) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  },
  decrementKluiten: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await decrementKluiten(req.params.username, req.body.requiredKluiten);
      res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (e) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  }
}
```

I've also added error handling in case something goes wrong, the server responds with a `500 Internal Server Error` status code.

Judging by these lines in your `TwitchAPI` class:

```
const rawFoundUser = await fetch(`http://localhost:${PORT}/api/users/${userstate.username}`);
const foundUser = await rawFoundUser.json();
```

I assume you've tried to do `const foundUser = await fetch('...').json()`. This results in an error, but you can call the retuned value's methods and properties on the same line if you wrap the await expression in parentheses, like this:

```
const foundUser = await (await fetch('...')).json()`
```

If its methods does not return a Promise (i.e being synchronous), or you want to access a property, you can do:

```
const something = (await doSomethingAsync()).someMethod()
const somethingElse = (await doSomethingAsync()).property
```

I also noticed you're using template literals (backticks, `` ` ``) for most strings without doing any template interpolation, which could simply be replaced with `'` (single-quotes) or `"` (double-quotes).

Comment: When I try your shorter way of fetching the foundUser, foundUser logs as a pending promise, it only works when I split them up.

Comment: @Kevin Oh yeah you're right, my bad! The response's `json()` method actually *is asynchronous*, and returns a Promise. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Sorry 'bout that! :)